# How to use a cursor inside a loop in a PostgreSQL script

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a script for a PostgreSQL database which reads a table and prints its content. I have used the following code

```
declare myCursor cursor for
    select col1, col2 from tab1;
begin
    loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myCursor .col1+" "+myCursor.col2);
    end loop;
end;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have found out:

```
do $$
declare myCursor cursor for
    select col1, col2 from tab1;
begin
    for myIterator in myCursor loop
        raise notice '% %', myIterator.col1, myIterator.col2;
    end loop;
end $$;
```